# Diodes normal polarised with voltage below forward voltage

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electrical-engineering

Assume we have a circuit with a diode and a voltage source . The voltage source has potential 0.4V .If we polarise forward the diode ( p type region connected to cathode and n type region connected to anode ).The propability of the silicon's unpaired electrons to become free is increased , so does the propability of boron anions to be destroyed is decreased which means narrower depletion region.Now the n type free electrons propability to exist is greater.More boron anions are created in the p type region but less silicon holes (the propability of free electrons of both the depletion region and the n type material is bigger than the propability of the p type material ).Am I correct?

Comment: This is quite unclear. The probability of carrier generation is related to temperature. No boron will be destroyed. With a slight forward bias the width of the depletion layer will be reduced, that is all.

Comment: Nah here we go again.Yes it is dependent to temperature because the electrons gain energy and have a bigger propability of becoming free charge carriers.